# What is the function of the « que » in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

> Vous venez à peine de commencer à cuisiner **que** vous y renoncez déjà ?

I have no trouble understanding the meanings of the two phrases before and after the word "que". But I have no idea why in this sentence the "que" is used like "et". What is the grammatical explanation behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Ortolang](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que), *que* is the second element of a conjunction (*locution conjonctive* in French), used to express anteriority, simultaneity or posteriority:

> α) [Que est le 2e élém. d'une loc. conj. exprimant l'antériorité, la simultanéité ou la postériorité] *On songera à ce musicien invisible qui joue derrière la scène pendant que l'acteur touche un clavier dont les notes ne résonnent point* (Bergson, Essai donn. imm., 1889, p. 119.
>
> SYNT. *Avant que, après que, jusqu'à ce que, d'ici à ce que, tant que, aussi longtemps que, à mesure que, toutes les fois que, chaque fois que, pendant que, tandis que, cependant que.*
>   − [En sub. inverse]<sup>1</sup>
>   ♦ À peine ... que. *À peine le médecin avait-il disparu, que Mme Josserand sortit de la pièce avec Mme Dambreville* (Zola, Pot-Bouille, 1882, p. 156).
>   ♦ [Après une princ. négative] *Il n'avait pas fait dix pas qu'il apercevait l'autocar, qui venait de s'arrêter. Il y monta. Ils n'étaient que trois voyageurs dans le car* (Montherl., Célibataires, 1934, p. 900).

In the first bullet point, it isn't easy to translate *a peine... que...* . An option would be *Hardly... when...* or *No sooner... than...*:

- **À peine** le médecin avait-il disparu, **que** Mme Josserand sortit de la pièce avec Mme Dambreville = **Hardly** had the doctor disappeared **when** Mrs. Josserand left the room with Mrs. Dambreville.

I would translate *que* in the second bullet point as *but*, keeping in mind that *que* is used with negative polarity items:

- Ils n'étaient **que** trois voyageurs dans le car = There were **but** three passengers in the bus.

---

<sup>1: La [subordination inverse](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00931848/document)<sup>PDF</sup> makes subordinate clauses into main clauses, and main clauses into subordinate ones: « On trouve des subordonnées commençant par *que*, après une proposition principale, qui, si l'on reconstruit la phrase avec une autre conjonction de subordination, deviennent principales tandis que la principale devient subordonnée... » (Gougenheim, 1938), which gererally results in a sentence following the natural order of events (i.e., the doctor disappears *and then* both ladies leave the room).</sup>

Comment: Hi. Am I right in thinking that the phrase "venir à peine de" **triggers** the use of "que" with the meaning "hardly ... when/before ..."?

Comment: @LUNA Indeed you're right.

Comment: A quick thank you for the confirmation.