# Why does "I was barely sitting when someone knocked on the door" translate to "Je suis à peine assis que l'on frappa à la porte"?

Tags: grammaire

I don't understand how "When someone" translates to "Que l'on" in

> Je suis à peine assis que l'on frappa à la porte

Because I'd understand if it was

> Je suis à peine assis quand on frappa à la porte

Why does que le translate into when?

Comment: This presence of **l'** has already been answered (several times actually) [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17340/358) and [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/9012/358) and [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1030/358) maybe more ... [one of this answers is in English](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1030/358). But there's another problem in the sentence - tenses "suis à peine" and "on frappa" just don't go together..  And if you have a query about *à peine **que*** [here's an answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/19304/358).